# All figures refers as Figure 1

Tags: labels

I have a following problem, all figures in the text are referred as Figure 1, but when I click on the Figure 1 it refers to the right figure (that is Figure 1, Figure 2, Figure 3).

My main.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}



\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}

\usepackage{epsfig,epsf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{array}
%
\usepackage[shadow,colorinlistoftodos,disable]{todonotes}                % use the option: "disable" to switch off the printing of the comments!
%\usepackage[shadow,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}       % option: disable is on => comments hidden
\newcommand{\CT}[1]{\todo[size=\tiny,color=green!40]{#1}}          % Christian
\newcommand{\LD}[1]{\todo[size=\tiny,color=blue!20]{#1}}         % Libor
\definecolor{myurlcolor}{rgb}{0,0,0.55}
\usepackage[pdftitle={Learning from Law Enforcement}, pdfauthor={Libor Dusek and Christian Traxler}, pdfstartview={FitH}, colorlinks=true, hyperfootnotes=false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=myurlcolor]{hyperref}

\usepackage[compact,noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{*2.75}{*1.2}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{*2.25}{*1.0}

\topmargin-1cm \topskip0.1cm \headsep0.1cm
\setlength{\footnotesep}{8pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.5pt plus 1.75pt minus 1.75pt}

\setlength{\unitlength}{2cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{12.4cm} % JEEA

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-2pt} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{11pt} % JEEA
\setlength{\topmargin}{-10pt} \setlength{\textheight}{23.75cm}
%

%
\interfootnotelinepenalty=6000
\clubpenalty=8000
\widowpenalty=12000
\hyphenpenalty=9000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} % JEEA
\usepackage{amsfonts} % JEEA
\usepackage{amssymb} % JEEA
\usepackage{amsmath} % JEEA
\usepackage{indentfirst} % JEEA



\begin{document}



% -------------------------


%%\newpage
\input{03_Predictions}

\input{30_Figures}


\end{document}
```

03_Predictions.tex:

```
\section{Theoretical Framework} \label{sec:predictions}
\enlargethispage*{0.5cm}

This should be Figure 1 but it is Figure~\ref{fig:updating-illu1}. This should be Figure 2 but it is Figure~\ref{fig:rd_ticketed}. This should be Figure 3 but it is Figure~\ref{fig:rd-main-cut1}.
```

30_Figures.tex:

```
\section*{Figures}
%


\begin{figure}[ht!]

    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_fine_top_comp.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_coarse_v2_top_wo_comp.pdf}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_fine_bottom_comp.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_coarse_v2_bottom_wo_comp.pdf}\\
    

    {\scriptsize \caption{BLABLA}}

    \label{fig:updating-illu1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage



\begin{figure}[ht!]
\let\center\empty
\let\endcenter\relax
\centering

      %


\begin{subfigure}[Enforcement Cutoff]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{FIG/1B2_RD_ticketed_a4_f4.png}}
      \end{subfigure}
      \vspace{0.25cm}
%
      \begin{subfigure}[High-fine Cutoff]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{FIG/11B2_RD_treated_high_a4_f4.png}}
      \end{subfigure}
%
{\scriptsize
\caption{BLABLA}}

\label{fig:rd_ticketed}
\end{figure}




\clearpage

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------




\begin{figure}[ht!]
\let\center\empty
\let\endcenter\relax
\centering

      

  \begin{adjustbox}{center}
  \parbox{1.1\textwidth}{\lineskip=0pt
    \begin{subfigure}[Speeding, enforcement cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/1B2_RD_speeding_a4_f4.png}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[Speeding, high-fine cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/11B2_RD_speeding_a4_f4.png}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[Speed, enforcement cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/1B2_RD_relspeedm_a4_f4.png}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[Speed, high-fine cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/11B2_RD_relspeedm_a4_f4.png}}
     \end{subfigure}}
  \end{adjustbox}
%
{\scriptsize \caption{BLABLA}}
\label{fig:rd-main-cut1}%
\end{figure}
```

Can you help me please, how can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have no `\caption` so the `\label` will pick up the last referencable number which is probably your section counter. unrelated but don't load the epsf and epsfig in any documents written this century.

Comment: also don't do `\let\center\empty \let\endcenter\relax` things will break eventually if you redefine core latex commands like this (and it is doing nothing useful here)

Comment: unrelated but `\usepackage{ae,aecompl}` were both obsolete by 1990 and `\usepackage{epsfig,epsf}` were both obsolete by 1994. None of those packages should be in current documents.

Comment: Using `{\scriptsize \caption{BLABLA}}` is not a good idea, for one scriptsize never applies to caption that way (the size is reset before the caption is typeset) but even worse, the outer brace set hides the data `\label` is suppose to pick up. So you're instead hitting the lastest referable thing perhaps a section with the number 1

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. I created a MWE, a minimal working example based on your given code, reduced by all not needed package calls for this issue.

The main issues in your code are (see also the comments to the question):

- The `\lable` has to **follow directly** the `\caption` command.
- `epsf` and `epsfig` are outdated nowadays.
- also don't do `\let\center\empty` and `\let\endcenter\relax`.
- `\usepackage{ae,aecompl}`: both packages were obsolete by 1990
- Using {\scriptsize \caption{BLABLA}} is not a good idea, for one scriptsize never applies to caption that way (the size is reset before the caption is typeset) but even worse, the outer brace set hides the data `\label` is suppose to pick up. So you're instead hitting the lastest referable thing perhaps a section with the number 1.
- Use `geometry` instead setting margins manually ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% <==========================================

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%
\usepackage[shadow,colorinlistoftodos,disable]{todonotes}                % use the option: "disable" to switch off the printing of the comments!
%\usepackage[shadow,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}       % option: disable is on => comments hidden
\newcommand{\CT}[1]{\todo[size=\tiny,color=green!40]{#1}}          % Christian
\newcommand{\LD}[1]{\todo[size=\tiny,color=blue!20]{#1}}         % Libor
\definecolor{myurlcolor}{rgb}{0,0,0.55}
\usepackage[%
  pdftitle={Learning from Law Enforcement}, 
  pdfauthor={Libor Dusek and Christian Traxler}, 
  pdfstartview={FitH}, colorlinks=true, hyperfootnotes=false, 
  linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=myurlcolor
]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

%\input{03_Predictions}
\section{Theoretical Framework}\label{sec:predictions}
\enlargethispage*{0.5cm}

This should be Figure 1 but it is Figure~\ref{fig:updating-illu1}. 
This should be Figure 2 but it is Figure~\ref{fig:rd_ticketed}. 
This should be Figure 3 but it is Figure~\ref{fig:rd-main-cut1}.

%\input{30_Figures}
\section*{Figures}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_fine_top_comp.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_coarse_v2_top_wo_comp.pdf}\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_fine_bottom_comp.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{FIG/_updating_coarse_v2_bottom_wo_comp.pdf}\\
  \caption{BLABLA1}\label{fig:updating-illu1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[Enforcement Cutoff]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{FIG/1B2_RD_ticketed_a4_f4.png}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  \begin{subfigure}[High-fine Cutoff]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{FIG/11B2_RD_treated_high_a4_f4.png}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{BLABLA2}\label{fig:rd_ticketed}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{center}
  \parbox{1.1\textwidth}{\lineskip=0pt
    \begin{subfigure}[Speeding, enforcement cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/1B2_RD_speeding_a4_f4.png}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[Speeding, high-fine cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/11B2_RD_speeding_a4_f4.png}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[Speed, enforcement cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/1B2_RD_relspeedm_a4_f4.png}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[Speed, high-fine cutoff]{%{.6\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{FIG/11B2_RD_relspeedm_a4_f4.png}}
     \end{subfigure}}
  \end{adjustbox}
\caption{BLABLA3}\label{fig:rd-main-cut1}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]